# combining two columns separated by semicolons in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset

```
ID  REGION  NUMTYPE
NY  us;ne   1015; 10x16
BO  us;ne   1015; 10x17
ID  nonus   1018
```

I would like to add another column "REGION_NUMTYPE" which has all the combinations of region and num type per row separated by the ";"

```
ID  REGION  NUMTYPE             REGION_NUMTYPE
NY  us;ne   1015; 10x16     us1015; us10x16;ne1015;ne10x16
BO  us;ne   1015; 10x17     us1015; us10x17;ne1015;ne10x17
ID  nonus   1018                nonus1018
```

Is there a simple way to do this ? Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way would be a double loop.

```
data want;
set have;
format Region_NumType $2000.; /*Modify size if needed*/


do i=1 to countw(region,";");
   do j=1 to countw(NumType,";");
      Region_NumType = cats(Region_NumType,scan(region,i,";"),scan(NumType,j,";"),";");
   end;
end;

run;
```